# Remove NAs from variables feeding into tbl_uvregression and geepack::geeglm without keeping only complete records

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm using gtsummary::tbl_uvregression to construct a univariate regression table modeled with geepack::geeglm.

Some variables contain NA values that are breaking the GEE models in the table.

> x There was an error constructing model `geepack::geeglm(formula = tts_participant ~ omb_race, data = ., family = poisson, id =` School Name`, corstr = "independence", scale.fix = TRUE)` See error below.
> Error in `mutate_cols()`:
> ! Problem with `mutate()` column `model`.
> i `model = map(...)`.
> x Error in geese.fit(xx, yy, id, offset, soffset, w, waves = waves, zsca, : nrow(zsca) and length(y) not match
> Caused by error:
> ! Error in geese.fit(xx, yy, id, offset, soffset, w, waves = waves, zsca, : nrow(zsca) and length(y) not match

You would generally set data = na.omit(data) for geepack::geeglm. However, I only want to remove NAs for the variables that I'm looking at in the table. na.action = na.omit does not work. I would like to avoid computing a gtsummary::tbl_uvregression table for each individual variable.

How do I instruct tbl_uvregression to remove the NAs only for the specific model being generated. Here is my attempt:

```
tbl_uvregression(
method = geepack::geeglm,
y = tts_participant,
include = -`School Name`,
method.args = list(
  family = poisson,
  data = na.omit(data),
  #na.action = na.omit,
  id = `School Name`,
  corstr = "independence",
  scale.fix = TRUE
),
exponentiate = TRUE,
add_estimate_to_reference_rows = FALSE
```

)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `geepack::geeglm()` is funny how it doesn't handle the NA values for us. When I've come across this, I write a small wrapper function for `geeglm()` that deletes the missing values before passing to `geeglm()`. Example below! Happy Programming!

```r
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.2'

my_geeglm <- function(formula, data, id, ...) {
  # capture id input (since it's unquoted)
  id <- rlang::enexpr(id)
  
  # keep compelte cases amoung the variables needed in the model
  data <-
    select(data, all_of(all.vars(formula)), !!id) %>%
    dplyr::filter(complete.cases(.))
  
  # build GEE model
  rlang::inject(
    geepack::geeglm(
      formula = formula,
      data = data, 
      id = !!id, # inserting unquoted id column name
      ...
    )
  )
}

data(dietox, package = "geepack")

dietox %>%
  select(Pig, Weight, Cu, Feed) %>%
  tbl_uvregression(
    y = Weight, 
    method = my_geeglm,
    method.args = list(id = Pig, family = poisson("identity"), corstr = "ar1"),
    include = -Pig
  ) %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable to show in SO
```

| **Characteristic** | **N** | **Beta** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cu | 861 |  |  |  |
| Cu000 |  | — | — |  |
| Cu035 |  | -0.49 | -3.5, 2.5 | 0.7 |
| Cu175 |  | 1.8 | -1.9, 5.5 | 0.3 |
| Feed | 789 | 0.43 | 0.42, 0.45 | <0.001 |

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>